# Undo [UIGestureRecognizer* requireGestureRecognizerToFail]

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, memory-management, uigesturerecognizer

Is there a way to undo requireGestureRecognizerToFail.

I set up a dependency between two UIGestureRecognizers with requireGestureRecognizerToFail like this.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer* tgr1 = [UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget ...];
UITapGestureRecognizer* tgr2 = [UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget ...];
[tgr1 requireGestureRecognizerToFail: tgr2];
... 
// later in the code
[tgr2 release];
```

How do I unregister tgr2 with tgr1? 
Does tgr2 actually released or does tgr1 now have a reference? 
If not, will releasing tgr2 cause problems?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your questions:

**How do I unregister tgr2 with tgr1?**

You have many options.

1. You can remove it from the view.
2. You can disable tgr2.
3. To keep the two recognizes you will need to create a new recognizer equal that was require to fail and add it, I do not know how to only remove the dependence between they, and do not know if is there a way.

**Does tgr2 actually released or does tgr1 now have a reference?**

tgr2 will not have the the retain count incremented when you add to tgr1 requireGestureRecognizerToFail with tgr2.

**If not, will releasing tgr2 cause problems?**

No, it will no cause problem, only that tgr2 will always fail and it will call tgr1

Comment: Hey, do you have a source for these claims? It appears to work in practice, but has Apple or an Apple employee ever said that the behavior is contractual?

Comment: @AndreyTarantsov I do not remember, but I used to work a lot with gestures, maybe some of then are not from a document but from test that I did.